# Magento cron script "Call to undefined method"

Tags: php, xml, magento, csv, cron

I'm getting a PHP fatal error on a cron script used for Commission Junction. It seems in the error_log it keeps updating with

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Data::getEscapedCSVData() in /home/lovescen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php on line 269
```

The code on line 269 is
`$escapedValue = Mage::helper("core")->getEscapedCSVData(array($value));`

And here is the entire code in Csv.php.

```js
<?php
    /**
     * Magento
     *
     * NOTICE OF LICENSE
     *
     * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
     * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
     * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
     * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
     * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
     * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
     * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
     *
     * DISCLAIMER
     *
     * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
     * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
     * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
     *
     * @category    Mage
     * @package     Mage_Dataflow
     * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
     * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
     */


    /**
     * Convert csv parser
     *
     * @category   Mage
     * @package    Mage_Dataflow
     * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
     */
    class Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Csv extends Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Abstract
    {
        protected $_fields;

        protected $_mapfields = array();

        public function parse()
        {
            // fixed for multibyte characters
            setlocale(LC_ALL, Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode().'.UTF-8');

            $fDel = $this->getVar('delimiter', ',');
            $fEnc = $this->getVar('enclose', '"');
            if ($fDel == '\t') {
                $fDel = "\t";
            }

            $adapterName   = $this->getVar('adapter', null);
            $adapterMethod = $this->getVar('method', 'saveRow');

            if (!$adapterName || !$adapterMethod) {
                $message = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Please declare "adapter" and "method" nodes first.');
                $this->addException($message, Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Exception::FATAL);
                return $this;
            }

            try {
                $adapter = Mage::getModel($adapterName);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $message = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Declared adapter %s was not found.', $adapterName);
                $this->addException($message, Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Exception::FATAL);
                return $this;
            }

            if (!method_exists($adapter, $adapterMethod)) {
                $message = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Method "%s" not defined in adapter %s.', $adapterMethod, $adapterName);
                $this->addException($message, Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Exception::FATAL);
                return $this;
            }

            $batchModel = $this->getBatchModel();
            $batchIoAdapter = $this->getBatchModel()->getIoAdapter();

            if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('files')) {
                $file = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getTempVarDir().'/import/'
                    . urldecode(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('files'));
                $this->_copy($file);
            }

            $batchIoAdapter->open(false);

            $isFieldNames = $this->getVar('fieldnames', '') == 'true' ? true : false;
            if (!$isFieldNames && is_array($this->getVar('map'))) {
                $fieldNames = $this->getVar('map');
            }
            else {
                $fieldNames = array();
                foreach ($batchIoAdapter->read(true, $fDel, $fEnc) as $v) {
                    $fieldNames[$v] = $v;
                }
            }

            $countRows = 0;
            while (($csvData = $batchIoAdapter->read(true, $fDel, $fEnc)) !== false) {
                if (count($csvData) == 1 && $csvData[0] === null) {
                    continue;
                }

                $itemData = array();
                $countRows ++; $i = 0;
                foreach ($fieldNames as $field) {
                    $itemData[$field] = isset($csvData[$i]) ? $csvData[$i] : null;
                    $i ++;
                }

                $batchImportModel = $this->getBatchImportModel()
                    ->setId(null)
                    ->setBatchId($this->getBatchModel()->getId())
                    ->setBatchData($itemData)
                    ->setStatus(1)
                    ->save();
            }

            $this->addException(Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Found %d rows.', $countRows));
            $this->addException(Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Starting %s :: %s', $adapterName, $adapterMethod));

            $batchModel->setParams($this->getVars())
                ->setAdapter($adapterName)
                ->save();

            //$adapter->$adapterMethod();

            return $this;

    //        // fix for field mapping
    //        if ($mapfields = $this->getProfile()->getDataflowProfile()) {
    //            $this->_mapfields = array_values($mapfields['gui_data']['map'][$mapfields['entity_type']]['db']);
    //        } // end
    //
    //        if (!$this->getVar('fieldnames') && !$this->_mapfields) {
    //            $this->addException('Please define field mapping', Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Exception::FATAL);
    //            return;
    //        }
    //
    //        if ($this->getVar('adapter') && $this->getVar('method')) {
    //            $adapter = Mage::getModel($this->getVar('adapter'));
    //        }
    //
    //        $i = 0;
    //        while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, null, $fDel, $fEnc)) !== FALSE) {
    //            $row = $this->parseRow($i, $line);
    //
    //            if (!$this->getVar('fieldnames') && $i == 0 && $row) {
    //                $i = 1;
    //            }
    //
    //            if ($row) {
    //                $loadMethod = $this->getVar('method');
    //                $adapter->$loadMethod(compact('i', 'row'));
    //            }
    //            $i++;
    //        }
    //
    //        return $this;
        }

        public function parseRow($i, $line)
        {
            if (sizeof($line) == 1) return false;

            if (0==$i) {
                if ($this->getVar('fieldnames')) {
                    $this->_fields = $line;
                    return;
                } else {
                    foreach ($line as $j=>$f) {
                        $this->_fields[$j] = $this->_mapfields[$j];
                    }
                }
            }

            $resultRow = array();

            foreach ($this->_fields as $j=>$f) {
                $resultRow[$f] = isset($line[$j]) ? $line[$j] : '';
            }
            return $resultRow;
        }

        /**
         * Read data collection and write to temporary file
         *
         * @return Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Csv
         */
        public function unparse()
        {
            $batchExport = $this->getBatchExportModel()
                ->setBatchId($this->getBatchModel()->getId());
            $fieldList = $this->getBatchModel()->getFieldList();
            $batchExportIds = $batchExport->getIdCollection();

            $io = $this->getBatchModel()->getIoAdapter();
            $io->open();

            if (!$batchExportIds) {
                $io->write("");
                $io->close();
                return $this;
            }

            if ($this->getVar('fieldnames')) {
                $csvData = $this->getCsvString($fieldList);
                $io->write($csvData);
            }

            foreach ($batchExportIds as $batchExportId) {
                $csvData = array();
                $batchExport->load($batchExportId);
                $row = $batchExport->getBatchData();

                foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
                    $csvData[] = isset($row[$field]) ? $row[$field] : '';
                }
                $csvData = $this->getCsvString($csvData);
                $io->write($csvData);
            }

            $io->close();

            return $this;
        }

        public function unparseRow($args)
        {
            $i = $args['i'];
            $row = $args['row'];

            $fDel = $this->getVar('delimiter', ',');
            $fEnc = $this->getVar('enclose', '"');
            $fEsc = $this->getVar('escape', '\\');
            $lDel = "\r\n";

            if ($fDel == '\t') {
                $fDel = "\t";
            }

            $line = array();
            foreach ($this->_fields as $f) {
                $v = isset($row[$f]) ? str_replace(array('"', '\\'), array($fEnc.'"', $fEsc.'\\'), $row[$f]) : '';
                $line[] = $fEnc.$v.$fEnc;
            }

            return join($fDel, $line);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve csv string from array
         *
         * @param array $fields
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCsvString($fields = array()) {
            $delimiter  = $this->getVar('delimiter', ',');
            $enclosure  = $this->getVar('enclose', '');
            $escapeChar = $this->getVar('escape', '\\');

            if ($delimiter == '\t') {
                $delimiter = "\t";
            }

            $str = '';
            foreach ($fields as $value) {

                $escapedValue = Mage::helper("core")->getEscapedCSVData(array($value));
                $value = $escapedValue[0];

                if (strpos($value, $delimiter) !== false ||
                    empty($enclosure) ||
                    strpos($value, $enclosure) !== false ||
                    strpos($value, "\n") !== false ||
                    strpos($value, "\r") !== false ||
                    strpos($value, "\t") !== false ||
                    strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
                    $str2 = $enclosure;
                    $escaped = 0;
                    $len = strlen($value);
                    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
                        if ($value[$i] == $escapeChar) {
                            $escaped = 1;
                        } else if (!$escaped && $value[$i] == $enclosure) {
                            $str2 .= $enclosure;
                        } else {
                            $escaped = 0;
                        }
                            $str2 .= $value[$i];
                    }
                    $str2 .= $enclosure;
                    $str .= $str2.$delimiter;
                } else {
                    $str .= $enclosure.$value.$enclosure.$delimiter;
                }
            }
            return substr($str, 0, -1) . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Not sure how to fix this problem. If I could get some help I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is the code from my `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php` file: http://pastie.org/10815259

Answer (score 1):

Does the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php` have the `getEscapedCSVData` function in it?

It appears that this function is added by SUPEE-7405.  Have you patched your store with this SUPEE?

Comment: Hmmm no, It doesn't appear to have that function. Should it or should it not have that function? Should I add it in somewhere? Here is the code from my Data.php: http://pastie.org/10815259

And yes I tried patching the site with SUPEE-7405 not too long ago. The site was also updated from 1.9.2 to 1.9.4

Comment: So I went ahead and downloaded a copy of Magento 1.9.2.4 and found the Data.php file, then copied those functions that were added at the bottom to my Data.php file. It seems you were right, the cron jobs are now finally updating with no errors. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my case some previous programer have copy the file

**from core**

\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php

**to local**

app\code\local\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php

and then apply SUPE PATCH 7405... 
it cause that all modifications made by SUPE in data.php where rewrite by the old ones in local folder...
Solution: copy the new data.php to local or made a extension of class (better solution)